# How to recover the file "/etc/init.d/skeleton"?

Tags: linux, raspbian

I accidentally remove my file `/etc/init.d/skeleton`.

Where can I get that file again?

My distribution is Raspbian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-install `initscripts` (as `root`):

```
apt-get --reinstall install initscripts
```

To figure this out for yourself in future:

```
apt-file search /etc/init.d/skeleton
```

You may need to install `apt-file` and run `apt-file update` as `root` first.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480897/5132 `/etc/init.d/skeleton` is no more.